# How to force Visio 2010 to start without a new blank template

Tags: windows-7, microsoft-visio-2010

Is there a way to force Visio 2010 on Win7 to start up without opening a new blank template?

In other words, when Visio 2010 starts, it always brings up a new Viso template (similar to what Word does). Is there a way to suppress this behavior so only the Viso Shell starts up?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The command switch is:

```
/nonew
```

Reference:

> http://office.microsoft.com/en-us/visio-help/command-line-switches-for-microsoft-visio-2010-HA010378910.aspx